# Hide button in round button-group with Foundation

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation-5

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 and I want to use a button stack with rounded buttons. However, some of the buttons I want hidden. For example, I have code which in essence is

```
<ul class="round button-group">
  <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">Button 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">Button 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">Button 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="button tiny">Button 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In Javascript I then hide buttons. Previous, I didn't use a button-group and I was able to simply toggle the 'hide' class on the button's 'a' tag (using JQuery). However, now that I am using a button-group and the buttons form a nice rounded bar, if I hide the first or last button, the look of the bar is broken - the new ends don't curve nicely.

Any idea how I can hide button 1, and then have button 2 (automatically?) have nice rounded left corners?

Comment: The curved buttons in Foundation work using `::first-child` and `::last-child`. Thus if you remove any item it looks smooth with rounded corners. Maybe it is an option for you to literally remove the unused buttons and re-insert them if needed using JS.

Comment: Thanks - that would work. However, it feels a little ugly to have to rebind the buttons after they are created a second time.

Comment: Any other options involves extending or editing the Foundation CSS to use `.first` and `.last` item classes in addition to `::first-child` and `::last-child` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) method will save you some trouble. Instead of hiding the buttons with CSS `detach` them and save the element to a variable for re-attach later. `detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed element.

This will allow Foundation to do it's job and maintain the correct rounded corners.

```
var first;

// Remove the first element
first = $('ul li:first-child').detach();

// Re-attach the element
first.prependTo('ul');
first = null;
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/ab4hLb5r/).

### Alternative

If you want to use a class-based approach you could do something like the following:

**jQuery**

```
// Toggle the visibility of the first element
$('ul li:first-child').toggle();

// Remove any existing psuedoFirst classes
$('ul li').removeClass('psuedoFirst');
// Assign the psuedoFirst class to the first visible element
$('ul li:visible').eq(0).addClass('psuedoFirst');
```

**CSS**

```
ul.round li.psuedoFirst a  {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1000px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1000px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/u58fca69/).